# Javascript function not triggerred

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript function in my `head` part of my HTML

```
<script>
   function validateForm() 
   {
     var apple = document.getElementById('apple').value;
     var err = 0;
     if (isNaN(apple)) {
        err += 1;
    }
    if (err != 0) {
        alert('Please check your input!');
        return false;
    } 
    else 
        return true; 
}
</script>
```

The form is shown below:

```
 <form name="orderForm" onSubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">  
    <div class="input-control text span5">
          <input class="span5" type="text" placeholder="Each @ $4.9" id="apple" name="apple" onChange='checkApple(this.value)'>
    </div>
  </form>
```

all brackets are completed and there is no typo.

When I submit the form with non numerical values, the form still gets submitted instead of error. May I know what's wrong with this ?

Comment: Have you tried not using JavaScript? `<input type="number" .../>`

Comment: use `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script>`

Comment: @Puneet It appears that the code is in HTML5, so no.

Answer (score 1):

You need to accept an event:

```
function validateForm(e) {
```

And prevent it:

```
if (err != 0) {
    e.preventDefault()
    ...
```

---

On an unrelated note, I would suggest that you restructure your code so it is less complicated, like:

```
var apple = document.getElementById('apple').value;
if (isNaN(apple)) {
    ...
```

No need for an `err` variable.

Comment: Wait what? Since when was "some string" not NaN (ie. a number)?

Comment: @Kolink Fixed (again)

Answer (score 0):

you must have input type="submit" or a button type="submit" in order for the onsubmit to trigger

Comment: Without it also submitted.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to perform a check for whether the input is a number, this may work:

```
function validateForm() 
{
     var apple = document.getElementById('apple').value;
     var err = 0;
     if (!isNaN(parseFloat(apple)) && isFinite(apple)) {
        err += 1;
     }
     if (err != 0) {
        alert('Please check your input!');
        return false;
     } 
     else 
        return true; 
}
```